# How to use the Amazon S3 Java API to perform getObject using an asynchronous call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java

I need to download a lot of files from S3 so I wrapped many calls to `s3Client.getObject(request, destination)` with futures, but there's no mention of it being blocking so I'm afraid I might run into a race condition where all the download calls were made but the files weren't really downloaded yet.

Is it safe to assume this api is blocking since there's no mention of it being async?

To clarify, by blocking I mean that the flow won't continue after the `s3Client.getObject(request, destination)` line until the download is finished.

[image]

Comment: No, there is no 'blocking'. What would you imagine would cause blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1478-L1549), it is indeed blocking the call ([invoke](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L5395)).

Comment: @smac2020 I assumed that the question was about the sync client and whether it is blocking - not about the async client which is obviously async.

Answer (score 1):

TO use the latest non-blocking code (AWS SDK for Java V2), refer to this Github example. This shows how to use **getObject** using the [asynchronous client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html).

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3AsyncStreamOps.java

Comment: good to know that there's an async client as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using SDK V2 with reactive streams integration.

- toBytes

  ```
  Mono.fromFuture(s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()))
            .map(ResponseBytes::asUtf8String)
            .flatMapMany(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("\n")))
            .map(stringLine -> ...)
  ```
- toFile

  ```
  Mono.fromFuture(s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toFile(Path.of(localFilePath))))
            .thenMany(Flux.using(
                            // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-
                            // This method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates lazily as the stream is consumed.
                            () -> Files.lines(Paths.get(localFilePath)),
                            Flux::fromStream,
                            Stream::close)
            .map(stringLine -> ...)
  ```

Comment: What is Mono and Flux?

Comment: they are implementations of the `Publisher` interface in the reactive stream specification. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive